# Storing Tokens in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, token, jwt

### The Question(s) =]

- Based on my research, it seems like storing web tokens in local storage is the preferred method over using cookies in order to prevent **CSRF** attacks (I am aware that local storage is susceptible to XSS attacks though these seem easier to prevent than CSRF). This being said, I have been unable to locate any ***relavant*** guides on utilizing *local storage* for this means...
- **I am looking for some help on understanding how the following works...**

  1. What is the *preferred* method/workflow to pass a server-signed token to the browser's local storage.
  2. Once the browser stores the token, how do I then use that stored token.

     - Do I need to stop the default submission of things like forms via JS and then send AJAX requests with the `authorization: Bearer <token>` header with every request?
     - When a user clicks a link to a resource owned by that user, how do I send that token to server to grant access to the protected resource?

### The Tools

- **Front-end**

  - HTML5 (Compiled from Handlebars)
  - JS
  - CSS (Compiled from SASS)
- **Back-end**

  - nodeJS (using Express)

*NOTE: I hope to edit this post with code samples in the future (once I get the hang of it lol), to help other confused people like myself in the future*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferred method is to return token with successful response from /users/login request (wherever you prefer, header or body). Then you put it into local storage.

Most important thing here, is that JWT can NOT be used without HTTPS. Otherwise you will end up passing credentials unprotected.

After acquiring of token, you should MANUALLY add it as a header to each request. Use some js ajax wrapper to simplify this task.

There is no way as far as I know to send custom headers with `<a href="">` elements. So I ended up passing additional token (some hash, not JWT) along with link `<a href="/some_protectded_page?token=...">`. But this is not optimal. If you render pages on server side, it is better to use sessions.

Comment: I prefer the stateless route....

What if you use cookie based jwt with stateless CSRF protection (I think paypal open sourced a library for this), would this approach work for server side rendering of pages while maintaining the advantages of stateless authentication?